# Check if child element already exists

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some code that appends a hidden form field with my current slide ID attached as a value, this is working to a point.

```
    var items = this._core.$stage.children();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            var curr_slide = items[i];
            var curr_slide_value = curr_slide.firstElementChild.getAttribute('data-hash');
            console.log(curr_slide);
            console.log(curr_slide_value);
            if(curr_slide.getElementsByTagName('form').length) {
                var form = curr_slide.getElementsByTagName('form');
                if(form[0].getElementsByName('slide') == null) {
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.value = curr_slide_value;
                    input.type = 'hidden';
                    input.name = 'slide';
                    form[0].appendChild(input);
                    alert("appended form");
                } else {
                    alert("did not append form");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This line does not work

```
if(form[0].getElementsByName('slide') == null) {
```

At this point I need to check if the input field with name "slide" already exists, and if not, add it.

For reference here is my form object

```
[form#gform_1, gform_1: form#gform_1, item: function, namedItem: function]
    0: form#gform_1
        0: textarea#input_1_1.textarea.medium
        1: textarea#input_1_2.textarea.medium
        2: textarea#input_1_3.textarea.medium
        3: textarea#input_1_4.textarea.medium
        4: input#gform_submit_button_1.gform_button.button
        5: input
        6: input#_gform_submit_nonce_1
        7: input
        8: input.gform_hidden
        9: input.gform_hidden
        10: input#gform_save_1.gform_hidden
        11: input#gform_resume_token_1.gform_hidden
        12: input.gform_hidden
        13: input.gform_hidden
        14: input#gform_target_page_number_1.gform_hidden
        15: input#gform_source_page_number_1.gform_hidden
        16: input
```

Comment: `if(!form[0].getElementsByName('slide')[0]) {`

Comment: @dandavis,`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for `if(!form[0].getElementsByName('slide')[0]) `

Comment: You can check for **.length()** as well, as getElementsByName gives out an array

Comment: if (!form[0].elements.slide) { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName` is not defined for `form`-elements.

The most compatible way should be:

```
if (!form[0].elements.slite) {
  // add <input name="slite"> to form[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(form[0].getElementsByName('slide').length == 0) {
```

Comment: `if(form[0].getElementsByName('slide').length == 0) {` gives error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Check your form[0] object! Because I tried with document.getElementsByName('blabla1') it work. Of course, the 'blabla1' is not available. And also document.getElementsByName('blabla1').length return 0

Comment: getElementsByName seems to be defined only for document

Comment: I added my form object to my post. @phylax